# How can I login with system user (prosody)?

Tags: ssh, login, user

I installed `prosody` XMPP server and now I'd like to create XMPP user via SSH (which basically means running custom script on that server). I assume that script should be run by `prosody` user, because of the access permissions. However, I'm not able to login with `prosody` user - since it's "system" user. How can I login as `prosody`?

I'm executing SSH from the script so sudo is not an option.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "creating user via ssh"?

Comment: I meant creating XMPP user. Thanks for note, I edited the question.

Comment: And again, it's hard for me to understand what you are trying to do and what issues do you have.

Comment: Do you have `prosody` user on the system with XMPP server? Do you have access to root account on server? Or access to some other user on the system? You note that you are "executing ssh" from some 'script'. Where is that script? On the server with XMPP or on your local machine? Why do you think that sudo is not an option?
If you want to get help then please try to be as descriptive as possible. Wish your question was so clear that misunderstanding would be impossible :)

Comment: have you tried 'ssh root@sshserver' ? My NAS calls the root account admin, but when you actually ssh in the account name is root.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to provide more info: I have prosody user. I can also be root, but I need to run the script as prosody (so the files created by the script are owned by prosody). I execute SSH from PHP script locate at different server.

Answer (score 0):

As root (or other user if you know the password of prosody), you can run a command as 'prosody' in this way:

`su -c COMMAND prosody`

I am not sure if it is what you are looking for.